# Is it possible to upload file through wcf service

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, wcf

Well Guys I have googled a lot and did not found something specific, I find that we can upload file using IHttpHandler. but I need to pass file location to WCF service and from there it can read bytes. I am using file path in my DataContract as DataMember.

```
[DataContract]
    public class JSchool
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int? Id;

                [DataMember]
        public string BrochurePath;
}
}
```

Next I am using jquery ajax to post the information. Can anyone help me out on this.

Answer (score 0):

So do you want your WCF service to read from the client machine and upload? Not possible.

Path that you are sending is of client machine, correct?

Comment: Yes it is of client machine.

Comment: If it is not possible so I guess there must be an alternative I googled and some results suggested that we can send stream.

Comment: yes, some application will need to send stream to WCF service which then can read and save. Similar thing that happens with browser when you upload a file....

Comment: can u please give an example